# How can I set up this conditional formatting in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

We create sections by highlighting an area in Excel 2010 and clicking ALL BORDERS.  We want to set it so that any time you type "REPLA" between columns J and Q, the line that "REPLA" is in will Fill Color to YELLOW, but ONLY the line within the Bordered area (between J and Q).

Also will need two other words that become other colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial on conditional formatting to build a solution for your needs:
[Automatically Highlight Max Value in a Data Table Using Conditional Formatting](http://exceltactics.com/automatically-highlight-max-value-data-table-using-conditional-formatting/)

Instead of using the formula:

```
=$G4=MAX($G:$G)
```

Replace it with your conditional:

```
=$G4="REPLA"
```

Note that the specified range in your case will also be changing to J:Q, etc.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF! Unfortunately I seem to suck at this and haven't been able to figure it out, even with your answer.  Is there any way you could be more specific in what I need to do?  I'm sure you're crazy busy, but it would help me out ALOT!!!

Comment: Please be specific about what you are struggling with and what you have questions about... Otherwise it is difficult to give assistance.